Cleaning up topology and hiding lines when shader auto smooth
I've created a plane model and I'm happy with the wings and engine topology the body of the plane has horrible topology. I used a Boolean modifier for the windows(I'm sure there are better ways but I'm not advanced enough to know them) there is also some ugly lines that go across the body when shaded smooth. Would anybody have any tips to fix these?




(Using Blender 3.6.8)
The fuselage is indeed "interesting". There are many issues to solve before trying to improve the shading.
In Edit Mode, the menu entry Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold could help to visualize where to improve the mesh (for example by merging vertices) as illustrated in the following figure:

Here are two examples of interior/duplicated edges or faces that should be merged:


In Edit Mode also, the menu entry Select > Select Sharp Edges could help to visualize where unexpected sharp edges are detected setting a very close to 90° Sharpness value as illustrated in the following figure:

As a conclusion, it might worth it to start from a "clean" thickness for the fuselage skin before cutting the windows, as most of issues are a consequence of extra faces inside this skin.

I'm not sure I understand do you suggest that I should solidify the model and then cut out the windows or are you suggesting that I clean up the mesh manually? I really appreciate the help, thank you!

Because you have issues at each window, I would recommand to solidify the fuselage, to make it a manifold. Then to cut out the windows. Otherwise, you will spend a lot of time, not being sure that every window is the same.
